# Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used error thrown when refreshing the page after login using facebook Id

Tags: php, facebook

This authorization code has been used error returned when refreshing the page after login using facebook id. I have read many blogs and I did not get any idea about this issue. Here is my code.

**fblogin.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once __DIR__.'\vendor\autoload.php';

//require 'functions.php';  

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

$appId='myappid';
$secretkey='mysecretkey';
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId,$secretkey);


$fb=new \Facebook\Facebook(['app_id'=>'myappid','app_secret'=>'mysecretkey','default_graph_version' => 'v2.4']);

// login helper with redirect_uri
//$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost:81/fblogin/fblogin.php',NULL,NULL);
$helper=$fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];    

if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])){

    //$accessToken=null;
    unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    unset($_SESSION['facebook_user']);
    session_unset();
}

try {

  // Logged in!
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
      } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getTraceAsString();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getTraceAsString();

}

 if (isset( $accessToken)) {
              $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
              $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
              $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

                    if(!isset($_SESSION['facebook_user'])) {
                    $response=$fb->get('/me?fields=id,name',$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

                    $user=$response->getGraphUser();

                      $_SESSION['facebook_user']=$user;

              }
        } elseif ($helper->getError()) {
          // The user denied the request
          exit;
        }
        else{
            $loginUrl=$helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:81/fblogin/fblogin.php',$permissions,'&');
        }
include 'index.php';
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php //
//session_start(); 

if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_user']))
{
    if($_SESSION['facebook_user'])!
    print_r($_SESSION['facebook_user']);
    echo '<a href=?logout>Logout</a>';
}
else
{
    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl.'">Login with FB</a>';
}
?>
```

**Steps:**
-Run fblogin.php and click "Login with FB" link
-Enter user name and password of FB
-Check User id and name is displayed with Logout link in Index.php
-Now refresh the browser.
-Verify "Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used" error thrown.

My question is, to resolve this problem, what i will do with the above code. If I have missed anything in my code, suggest me where i want to add or remove the line of code.

I am using Wamp server and Facebook SDK 5.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039756/facebook-this-authorization-code-has-been-used-typeoauthexception-code

Comment: No. If I enable this $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost:81/fblogin/fblogin.php',NULL,NULL); i am getting this error <br> " Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client, string given, called ".<br> Because, Facebookredirectloginhelper expects Oauth2client object. <br>" __construct(OAuth2Client $oAuth2Client, PersistentDataInterface $persistentDataHandler = null, UrlDetectionInterface $urlHandler = null, PseudoRandomStringGeneratorInterface $prsg = null)

Comment: Maybe they don't allow localhost servers to connect with their API server.